# How can I install Windows 10 store Apps offline

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, windows-store-app

Now my question is: how can I install Windows 10 Apps offline, under the following conditions:

1. The apps aren't published by Microsoft, because some of them were installed offline successfully, e.g (Fresh paint).
2. The apps that were downloaded to PC #1 (online),  able to install also on PC #2 (offline). I was able to install the apps offline only on the device were they had been downloaded to.

Note that I tried the methods as follows which didn't work for me:

1. Download apps from windows store via "Fiddler"
2. Backup apps and reistall them via "WSAppBak".
3. Created "Windows to go" (WTG) on USB flash drive via PC #1, online , And then installed apps on it, after that  ran WTG on PC #2, the offline one. The apps I had installed didn't work, but the in Windows included ones did.

The OS: Windows 10_x64 build 1703, both for PC #1 and #2.